# laravel sum collection ignore when the value is negative

Tags: php, laravel

i am using laravel sum method but when i return the `-1` value for sum of `2` items it returns the `0.2` which i want to ignore the sum if the negative values  here is my code below :

```
    return (object) [
                 'sum_of_prices' => $group->sum('sales_price'),
                 'sum_of_fullboard' => $group->sum('full_board_price'),
                 'sum_of_halfboard' => $group->sum('half_board_price')
     ];
```

here i want to bypass the sum of negative result and just pass a default value for negative or some thing and just sum posetive result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change negative value to zero with `sum()` callback:

```
return (object) [
    'sum_of_prices' => $group->sum(function ($item) {
        return $item->sales_price > 0 ? $item->sales_price : 0;
    }),
    'sum_of_fullboard' => $group->sum(function ($item) {
        return $item->full_board_price > 0 ? $item->full_board_price : 0;
    }),
    'sum_of_halfboard' => $group->sum(function ($price) {
        return $item->half_board_price > 0 ? $item->half_board_price : 0;
    })
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using laravel collection.

```
 return (object) [
             'sum_of_prices' => $group->filter(function($item){
                 return $item->sales_price >=0    
              })->sum('sales_price'),
             'sum_of_fullboard' => $group->filter(function($item){
                 return $item->full_board_price >=0    
              })->sum('full_board_price'),
             'sum_of_halfboard' => $group->filter(function($item){
                 return $item->half_board_price >=0    
              })->sum('half_board_price')
 ];
```